"Remember me" feature for login in TikiWiki site not working
I recently upgraded TikiWiki of my site from version 25 to version 27. I also upgraded PHP version from 7.4 to 8.3. Now "remember me" feature is not working and every time I visit my site I have to login again in my admin account. I tried it with different browsers and even on different computers. It is the same for other users of the site, if they return few hours latter they have to login again.
I already increased those directives in php.ini but without any effect:
session.cache_expire
session.gc_maxlifetime
session.cookie_lifetime
Any idea what might be causing the problem or how can I debug it?
EDIT: Added my relevant to this issue TikiWiki configuration.

UPDATE Problem seems fixed. I went to Control panel of my TikiWiki site then General -> General Settings
Here I saw "Session storage parameter" was set to "Default (from php.ini)". I changed it to Database and now it does remember me :) Either in old version of TikiWiki the the default was different or the old php.ini of PHP 7.4 was different but anyway, now it is fine.


Was the webserver restarted after applying the changes to php.ini?

Also, without seeing relevant code, there are MANY breaking changes between PHP versions 7.4 to 8.3, so I'd start looking to the webserver error log for possible clues.

Can we assume that you checked that the version of TikiWiki you upgraded to is listed as compatible with the version of PHP you upgraded to? Because if  you didn't, that could easily be a factor.

Thanks for the suggestions. Webserver was restarted also TikiWiki version 27 is compatible with PHP 8.3 - that was the reason to upgrade PHP as 7.4 was not supported. Now I am trying to catch the bug looking at the logs.

Please make sure the "Refresh the remember-me cookie expiration" (Preference name: cookie_refresh_rememberme) is enabled on your upgraded Tiki.
You can find it in the Settings on the "Registration & Log in" control panel (tiki-admin.php?page=login).

Yes, this option is enabled. I uploaded my current TikiWiki cookie configuration in the original post. I experimented with most options - giving the user the choice to set "remember me" instead of "Always", setting the duration to 1 week or 1 month, leaving domain name blank. Everything has no effect.
